# MySQL CURSOR ERROR 1193: Unknown system variable

Tags: mysql, database-cursor

I am creating a cursor for the first time.(referring [this site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html))
I made this so far(

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `abc`.`cursordemo` (IN start_date DATETIME,IN end_date DATETIME)
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE k1,k2,g,s,last_status VARCHAR(45);
  DECLARE b, c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT `key` FROM `abc`.`temp_weekly`;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;
 read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO k1;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    block_cursor:BEGIN
        DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT `key`,`group`,`status` FROM `abc`.`jira_local` WHERE `key` = k1 AND updateddate < end_date;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done1 = TRUE;
        OPEN cur2;
        REPEAT
            FETCH cur2 INTO k2,g,s;
            IF NOT done1 THEN


            IF s != last_status THEN
                CASE
                    WHEN s = 'verified' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                    WHEN s = 'closed' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                    WHEN s = 'to be scheduled' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                    WHEN s = 'deferred' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
/*'resolved','closed','to be scheduled','deferred','validated','assigned','l3 need more info','l2 need more info','need more info'*/
                    WHEN s = 'resolved' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                    WHEN s = 'validated' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                    WHEN s = 'assigned' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                    WHEN s = 'l3 need more info' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                    WHEN s = 'l2 need more info' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                    WHEN s = 'need more info' THEN
                    SET c = c +1;
                END CASE;
                SET last_status = s;
            END IF;
            END IF; 
        UNTIL NOT done1 END REPEAT;
        INSERT INTO ticketsResolvedCount values(k2,g,s,c);
    END block_cursor;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
END$$
```

What I am doing
1) read all keys from temp_weekly and iterate
2) find all the records from jira_local table for a particular key and count the number of times it was verified,resolved  etc.

Problem :
 When I compile this it gives an error

```
ERROR 1193: Unknown system variable 'done1'
```

Also, I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224248/using-cursor-in-a-loop-of-a-stored-procedure) link to create a stored procedure inside a loop

**UPDATE:**
After declaring `done/done1` my procedure looks like this

```
BEGIN

      DECLARE k1,k2,g,s,last_status VARCHAR(45);
      DECLARE b, c INT;
      DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT `key` FROM `abc`.`temp_weekly`;
        DECLARE done1 BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
        .
        .
        .
block_cursor:BEGIN
        DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT `key`,`group`,`status` FROM `abc`.`jira_local` WHERE `key` = k1 AND updateddate < end_date;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done1 = TRUE;
       .
       .
       .
```

this gives me

```
ERROR 1337: Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration
```

Comment: I do `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done1 = TRUE;` look after the 2nd cursor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to declare `done1` as you did with `done`:

From

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
```

to

```
DECLARE done, done1 INT DEFAULT FALSE;
            ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I thought done1 should be declared within 2nd block `block_cursor:BEGIN` otherwise how will the compiler know which `done/done1`  corresponds to which cursor

Comment: I found a good reference to work with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099837/1983854 . Cursors are a little tricky, so I strongly recommend you to learn how to do it just with one and then move on to two, three...

Comment: `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;` line is not declaring `done` variable. It's declaring a handler. `SET done = TRUE` is the body of the handler. Just seems like that's not clearly understood.

Comment: @nsr81 : yes I guess that is the problem I'll try declaring it and then compile

Comment: `ERROR 1337: Variable or condition declaration after cursor or handler declaration` it means you cannot declare anything after cursors or handlers.